# Any way I can detect the Undo command being invoked?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add an attached event to `TextBox` instances. The event would be named `UndoCommandInvoked` and as you'd guess it would be raised whenever a user types CTRL-Z on a modified `TextBox`.

(Now I am aware I could just handle key events and react on CTRL-Z being pressed, but the thing is however that I'd also like to react on `Undo` method being called.)

While researching on this issue I came to understand (and feel free to correct me if I got it wrong) that by default, `TextBox` instances have `ApplicationCommands.Undo` command attached to its `CommandBindings` property.

Is there a way I can successfully and safely extract that command and react on its execution?

Answer (score -1):

You understand correctly that undo is by default.

> Textbox has this feature by defualt

. 
your 2nd option will be add a queue and after every text or phrase enter it to that queue. you dont need an event for undo. Ctrl + Z has an ASCI code. put an if condition in Text change event, if the ASCI code is **(what ever you find the ASCI code could be for Ctrl +Z). if this ** is equal to the text come though text change you could dequeue your old text. 
i know this is the hard solution but if it is so desire, then its your only option, so far i think

Comment: As I said I need this event to be raised when `Undo` method gets called programmatically.

Comment: there is no undo event. but you could get a break point hit. if you put a if condition in text change event. That ASCI code story will come. i could tell you the asci code

Comment: *There is no undo event* I know, I'm trying to attach one. There *is* however an `Undo` *method*. Reacting on TextChanged event AFAIK won't allow me to react on it. This is why I'd like to hook to the actual application command. Are you saying there's no way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to achieve it with minimal code: (This is the code behind of a win form with a single textbox on it)
i have Google it, didn't implement it. but seems to be useful

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Stack<Func<object>> undoStack = new Stack<Func<object>>(); 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.U && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && undoStack.Count > 0)
            undoStack.Pop()();            
    }
    private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.KeyChar != 'u' || Control.ModifierKeys != Keys.Control)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            undoStack.Push(textBox.Text(textBox.Text));
        }
    }
}
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Func<TextBox> Text(this TextBox textBox, string text)
    {            
        return () => { textBox.Text = text; return textBox; };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is [tag:Winforms], I've mentionned [tag:WPF].